# How to access data controller / data model from ApiController?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I have a ScoreDataModelsController that contains the following Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Getnames()
        {
            return View(db.ScoreDataModels.ToList());
        }
```

In Views I have the corresponding ScoreDataModels folder containing Getnames.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.ScoreDataModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Get Names";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_emptyLayout.cshtml";
}

<table class="table">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

This all works fine. Now I would like to make this data (i.e. Names) accessible as json/XML using REST. I have managed to get the ApiController working with the standard settings and by opening http://.../api/Andi i get the values from the string[] in XML format:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class AndiController : ApiController
    {

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "und en dritte" };

  //Here I need help: ScoreDataModelsController sdm = new ScoreDataModelsController();
           // var res = from r in sdm


        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, instead of "value1, value2 ..." I would like to get the names from my ScoreDataModel / ScoreDataModelsController.

The ScoreDataModel looks like this. I have used this model to create the controller and view by scaffolding in Visual Studio:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ScoreDataModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I would very much appreciate if you could lead me into the right direction to get this REST API working with my existing data controller / data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a central class which holds your data access logic, something like this:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    public List<ScoreDataModel> GetNames()
    {
        return db.ScoreDataModels.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class to access your data from both the MVC controller and the api controller:

```
public class AndiController : ApiController
{
    private DataRepository dbRepo = new DataRepository();

    public IEnumerable<ScoreDataModel> Get()
    {
        List<ScoreDataModel> names = dbRepo.GetNames();
        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising, thanks. In which namespace can I find DatabaseContext?

Comment: That's your "db" object that you are using in the MVC controller.The entity framework database context class.And please mark as answered if it helps you

Comment: How can I access this object? In my ScoreDataModelsController a context was createed with "private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()" - how can I access this db variable from the DataRepository.cs?

Comment: Easy just instantiate private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(); inside the DataRepository class

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var data= db.ScoreDataModels.ToList()

                List<String>list=new List<String>();

                foreach(var r in data)
                {
                    list.add(r.Name);

                }


                return list;
```

Comment: make a comment if need any help

Comment: works perfect as well - thanks a lot. I just had to create the Databese context with 'ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();'